# Magento display tierprice on cart

Tags: magento, cart

I'm facing issues with displaying the tierprice of a product in the Cart and on the confirmation e-mail.

I only get piece price (tierprice + options / qty) but I wan't to show the tierprice of base product in overview.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id); //load product from id

```
if($product['tier_price'] != NULL) {
    foreach($pro['tier_price'] as $tierPrice){
        echo $tierPrice['price'].'<br/>';
    } }
```